# store all numbers from the array that has index 0 in another array in another function and calculate their average

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

float avg_km(int jogador[], int n) {
  #define MAX 1000

  int zero[MAX];
  int i, j = 0, sum = 0;
  float avg;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      zero[j] = jogador[i];
      j++;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    sum += zero[i];
  }

  avg = (float)sum / j;

  return avg;
}

void test_worldcup() {
  #define MAX 1000

  int jogador[MAX];
  int i = 0;
  float avg;

  while (scanf("%d", &jogador[i]) != EOF) {
    i++;
  }

  // chama a função avg_km para calcular a média dos valores do array com índice zero
  avg = avg_km(jogador, i);

  printf("%.2f\n", avg);
}

int main() {
  test_worldcup();

  return 0;
}
```

I am practicing some exercises to take an exam at the university in a month but I am stuck on this exercise that seems very easy but I don't know what to do. Supposedly I need to have a main function that "calls" another function called test_worldcup in this function I have to store the inputs and write the answer using another function called avg_km, what I need to do in this function is calculate the average of all the numbers with index 0 of all the arrays that were placed, this code is what I have until now but I don't know what else to do.

Any tip?

Comment: Why `if (i == 0) {` in the `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {` loop?

Comment: The whole idea of a second array and something special about index 0 makes no sense to me.  I wish educational exercises didn't dictate silly requirements like that.

Comment: Also, pre-processor stuff like `#define MAX 1000` is done before any compilation and does not respect the scope of braces `{}`.  For example, the `#define MAX` in `test_worldcup` could be removed, and it would still compile just fine.  The way it is here, you run the risk of "re-definition." Normally, stuff like that will be defined at the top.